# Neo4j - Spring get String list from labels

Tags: java, database, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

How can i retrieve in Spring a List from this query

```
MATCH (n) WITH DISTINCT LABELS (n) as labels RETURN labels
```

Which doesn't create a node, but return just some strings referred to all different labels in my neo4j database?

Comment: how are you executing this query in spring ?

Comment: @Query("MATCH (n) WITH DISTINCT LABELS (n) as labels RETURN labels")

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session.query` method that returns a `org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result`, you should have a column called `labels` that contains the labels returned by your query.

You can also use `@Query` in your repository like this:

```
  @Query("MATCH (n) WITH DISTINCT LABELS (n) as labels RETURN labels")
  List<String> findLabels();
```

Comment: Thanks Luanne, I'll try this tomorrow

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Oct 13 17:39:17 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "meta" (class org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.RowModelResult), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "row"]) at [Source: {"row":[["Employee"]],"meta":[null]}; line: 1, column: 31] (through reference chain: org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.RowModelResult["meta"])